# PHP Form Validation Error

Tags: php, forms, validation, registration

I got some great help earlier from StackOverflow and I have another problem.

What this does is it always gives the error that I haven't completed all the fields.

Here's my form function:

```
// Function with HTML to display form
function FormDisplay () {
    echo '<form action="MyRegister.php" method="post">';
    echo 'Username:';
    echo '<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="60"><br />';
    echo 'Password:';
    echo '<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="60"><br />';
    echo 'Confirm Password:';
    echo '<input type="password" name="password_confirm" maxlength="60"><br />';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"><br />';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

This function is called whenever the registration form is needed

Here is the code that validates the user input:

```
// Checks for field completion
function FieldComplete($user, $password, $password_confirm) {
    if (!isset($user, $password, $password_confirm) &&
        $user && $password && $password_confirm != "" || " ") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

// Validate fields using isset and FieldComplete (see above)
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username_original = $_POST["username"];
    $password_original = $_POST["password"];
    $password_confirm_original = $_POST["password_confirm"];

    $IsComplete = FieldComplete($username_original, $password_original, $password_confirm_original);
if(!$isComplete){
   FormDisplay();
   echo "* You did not complete all the required fields." . "<br />";
}
}else{
//display the form
    FormDisplay();
}
```

So this displays the form correctly, and all of my other validations are working perfectly (not shown here).

I'm not sure what's wrong, I have scoured the syntax and everything since the last time I was on here (about 3-4 hours ago)

Appreciate the feedback.

-ethan17458

Comment: Didn't think you could chain like this... My reading of "&& $user && $password &&" would be "AND $user == true, AND $password == true" - I think they all need $user != '' && $password != ''

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FieldComplete() will always return false because:

```
 if (!isset($user, $password, $password_confirm) &&
        $user && $password && $password_confirm != "" || " ")
```

Will always be true, due to the last logical "OR":

```
|| " "
```

If you are looking to validate that $user, $password, and $password_confirm are all set, non-blank, and not a single space, you want:

```
if (!isset($user, $password, $password_confirm) || $user == '' 
     || $user == ' ' || $password == '' || $password == ' ' 
     || $password_confirm == '' || $password_confirm == ' ')
```

Though probably what you are after is:

```
 if (!isset($user, $password, $password_confirm) ||
        trim($user) == '' || trim($password) == '' || trim($password_confirm) == '')
```

Which will ensure that all three are populated and not just whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, your conditions are incorrect. Change to something like:

```
if(!isset($user,$password,$password_confirm) || trim($user)=='' || trim($password)=='' || trim($password_confirm)==''){
```

You also have `$IsComplete` and `$isComplete`. These are not the same as PHP is case sensitive.

Simplify it and get rid of 'isComplete':

```
if(FieldComplete($username_original,$password_original,$password_confirm_original)){
FormDisplay();
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're over-complicating the validation...

`isset()` is wonderful for a simple "has my variable been instantiated" check... but it will give out false positives for empty and 0 values.

The example below is using empty and trim.  Trim will remove any white-spaces at the ends of the strings, and empty will check to see if it is "", null, 0, etc.

Hope it helps.

```
// Checks for field completion
function FieldComplete($user, $password, $password_confirm)
{
    if (empty(trim($user)) || empty(trim($password)) || empty(trim($password_confirm)))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```